# How do bitcoin nodes know their own external IP address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I'm studying the bitcoin source code and I have a doubt about if: Bitcoin nodes **still** follow the methods explained at the "Satoshi Client Node Discovery" wiki page?

More specifically, if they follow the explained local client's external address discovery method using external websites.

I didn't find any references/evidence of web requests being made to the ip address 91.198.22.70 or the checkip.dyndns.org web address in the code.

Was it removed at some point in time?

The Bitcoin source code version in question is the master branch at 2018/05/04 (v0.16).

Thanks in advance.

[GitHub Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin)

[Satoshi Client Node Discovery](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery#Local_Client.27s_External_Address)

Comment: This is used currently: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.cpp#L1499

Comment: @MCCCS Thks for your reply. Is it only done by UPnP? A lot of routers have the UPnP disabled.

Comment: Yes, only UPnP. You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/a4af4a66b2ce7e35b51944192e1045b16c8b082c/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.c#L299